# Is there an action/filter called when WP_Query->query is finished and assigns posts

Tags: wp-query, actions, customization

I took a look at the `WP_Query->get_posts()` function and couldn't see any action/filter that is called **AFTER** a query finishes.

I want to be able to manipulate the results once they are sent, rather than the query itself (Using a Human Name Parser to sort by last name).

I'm revamping an old site that alters the global `$wp_query->posts` right within `archive.php`, so I was just wondering if there was a way to take this logic completely out of the archive file and store it with my other CPT functionality.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The is the [`the_posts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2772) filter, which sounds like what you want.

```
function filter_the_posts($posts) {
  var_dump($posts);
}
add_filter('the_posts','filter_the_posts');
```

Comment: Perfect! I saw `the_post`, I think I must have been a little too far down in the caching area :). Cheers!